# TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got DeferredAttribute object at 0x000002B6ADE878D0

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am using a queryset in Django- whenever I run the server, it gives an error.

`TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000002B6ADE878D0`

It is something about the queryset of my form that causes the error.

I don't know whether its an issue with my *models.py* or my *forms.py*
I tried looking up this *DeferredAttribute object* on Google, but I didn't really see any answer that works for me.

**forms.py:**

```
from .models import Task, Categories
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.db.models import Q

class TaskForm(ModelForm):

    task_title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    task_description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)        
    due_date = forms.DateTimeField()    
    is_completed = forms.BooleanField()
    #categories = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label="---None---")

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['task_title', 'task_description', 'due_date', 'is_completed', 'categories', 'parent']        

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get all the categories from the database for that specific user
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # It is something about this line that causes the error
        self.fields['categories'].queryset = Categories.objects.filter(Q(user_id__isnull=True) | Q(user_id=user.id))
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from users.models import CustomUser
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class Categories(models.Model):
    category_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null = True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s ' % (self.category_type)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task_list')


class Task(models.Model):
    task_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    task_description = models.TextField()
    date_added =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date  = models.DateTimeField()
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    categories = models.ForeignKey('Categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Task"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tasks"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s ID: %s' % (self.task_title, self.last_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task_detail')
```

**CustomUser model:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    nationality = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=60)
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView , CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import TaskForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

class TaskListView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "tasks.html"

# This is the actual create view I am for using now
class TaskCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'create.html'
    form_class = TaskForm(get_user_model())
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')

# I am using this for a modal, but its not working so I fell back to the  normal create view
def task_create(request):
    form = TaskForm(get_user_model())
    context = {'form': form}
    html_form = render_to_string('tasks/partial_task_create.html',
        context,
        request=request,
    )
    return JsonResponse({'html_form': html_form})
```

Comment: It looks like you create `TaskForm` with as `user` parameter *not* a `User` object, but the `User` class.

Comment: Can you please show the related view(s)?

Comment: This query looks a bit excessive `Q(user_id__isnull=True) | Q(user_id=user.id)` Can user id be null? I think just `user_id=user.id` is enough. Also `TaskForm(get_user_model())` — the form class is initiated and has to be just TaskForm without params because it is a form class, not an instance.

Comment: `TaskForm(get_user_model())` does not make much sense.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I have added my *views.py* to the post; kindly check it out. Furthermore, I didn't really get your first comment. Please explain further. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @artembo. For the query: The app I am building is a todolist app. Each task can be categorized. The categories added by the programmer(admin) are represented by null in the user id field (Foreign key in Categories model). The categories added by  a specific user is represented by the user's id. So, for the query, I want to get the list of Categories created by the admin and that specific user.

Comment: @artembo, @WillemVanOnsem. I added , `TaskForm(get_user_model())` to pass in the current user. When i remove it, i get `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'` .. `\views.py", line 14, in TaskCreateView
    form_class = TaskForm()`

Comment: Pls remove the brackets () form TaskForm. Leave just form_class = TaskForm

Comment: @David.B: you need to pass a user *object*, not the user *class*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A statement like:

```
form = TaskForm(get_user_model())
```

does not make much sense. Indeed, `get_user_model()` returns a reference to the user *class*, not to a user *object* (like the logged in user). You can construct such a form with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def task_create(request):
    form = TaskForm(request.user)
    context = {'form': form}
    html_form = render_to_string('tasks/partial_task_create.html',
        context,
        request=request,
    )
    return JsonResponse({'html_form': html_form})
```

Here we use the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) to prevent user that are not logged in to access the view. This is useful, since in that case `request.user` is not a user object.

or in the [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) you can override the [**`get_form_kwargs`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) to :

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class TaskCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'create.html'
    form_class = TaskForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(user=self.request.user)
        return kwargs
```

In order to enforce a user to be logged in, we then use a [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: Thanks, it worked... Really appreciate your efforts. I have a question though: Does the class based view also return JSON? I am new to using Ajax and Django and I have not yet fully grasped the relationship between them yet. Can you also recommend some good resources? Thanks

Comment: @DavidB.: It just renders the template, so normally no, normally the get will return a HTML response, whereas a POST will, in case it is succeful, return a redirect to another page.

Comment: i still have a question: Is there a way to return Json response. I am implementing the CreateView in a bootstrap modal (I want to avoid [age refresh) and i want to use Ajax for validation.  Would I need to override the `as_view` or the `get` method for the Class based view? I saw something on [https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/03/21/class-based-views-vs-function-based-views.html] , but I didn't understand it. Thanks